# Error while calling web service method using external Jar from android

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I am Trying to Call some java method from the android device.my java method i am accessing through axis2 web service.

Here Is my full Java class in that i had Written two Methods to call From Adnroid Device .And Somehow Its just calling get_wav_byte()method Successfully but for another method its giving me error as follows

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/ConfigurationManager

this is the class in my external jar library that i m using in recognize_wave(String wavePath) method.
I have Also Checked that the edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/ConfigurationManager is available in jar file m including stilll its giving me error.I am givng you my full code of java and android as follows

JAVA METHOD :

```
package edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber;




import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.AudioFileDataSource;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
//import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

/** A simple example that shows how to transcribe a continuous audio file that has multiple utterances in it. */
public class Transcriber {

      //  private static final String PATH = "file:///D:\\Sound\\";




    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static String recognize_wave(String wavePath) throws MalformedURLException{




         String resultText="";
              URL audioURL;


               audioURL = new URL(wavePath);
               URL configURL = Transcriber.class.getResource("config.xml");

                ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(configURL);
                Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");

                /* allocate the resource necessary for the recognizer */
                recognizer.allocate();

                // configure the audio input for the recognizer
                AudioFileDataSource dataSource = (AudioFileDataSource) cm.lookup("audioFileDataSource");
                dataSource.setAudioFile(audioURL, null);

                // Loop until last utterance in the audio file has been decoded, in which case the recognizer will return null.
                Result result;
                while ((result = recognizer.recognize())!= null) {

                      resultText  = result.getBestResultNoFiller();
                        System.out.println(resultText);
                }

            return resultText;
        }

        public String get_wav_byte(byte[] wavbite,String path) throws IOException

        {


            String result1="null";
            //return result1;

             final String PATH = "file:///D:\\Sound\\";

            //System.out.println(bhavik1111);


            try
        {
            File dstFile = new File(path);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
                out.write(wavbite, 0, wavbite.length);

            out.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
        }


        try {
            result1=recognize_wave(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return result1;


 }



}
```

AND MY ANDROID CODE TO CALL THAT METHOD WITH KSOAP2 IS AS FOLLOWS :

```
package com.varma.samples.audiorecorder;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.MarshalBase64;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewDebug.FlagToString;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecorderActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int RECORDER_BPP =16;
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
    private static String AUDIO_WAV_FILE = "";
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 16000;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setButtonHandlers();
        enableButtons(false);







        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
    }

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }

    private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
        ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
        enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);
        enableButton(R.id.btnStop,isRecording);
    }

    private String getFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
    }

    private String getTempFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File tempFile = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

        if(tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    private void startRecording(){
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                        RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        },"AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    private void writeAudioDataToFile(){
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
        FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int read = 0;

        if(null != os){
            while(isRecording){
                read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                    try {
                        os.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    private void stopRecording(){
        if(null != recorder){
            isRecording = false;

            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }

        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
        deleteTempFile();
    }

    private void deleteTempFile() {
        File file = new File(getTempFilename());

        file.delete();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = 16000;
        int channels = 1;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;
    /// long byteRate = 256;

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
            totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

            while(in.read(data) != -1){
                out.write(data);
            }



            in.close();
            out.close();
            //////////////////


            AUDIO_WAV_FILE=outFilename;
            /////////////////


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
/////////////read wav file and convert to byte////////////////////
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {

        /*
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
        */
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        int read;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();


        return audioBytes;



    }

    //////////////////////////////////////
    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
            FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
            long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
            long byteRate) throws IOException {

        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        out.write(header, 0, 44);


    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnStart:{
                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");





                    enableButtons(true);





                    startRecording();

                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnStop:{
                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                    enableButtons(false);
                    stopRecording();

                     File source_for_byte=new File( AUDIO_WAV_FILE);
                        byte[] temp = new byte[(int) source_for_byte.length()];




                        try {
                            temp=getBytesFromFile(source_for_byte);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        //byte[] strBase64 = Base64.encode(temp, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        //Request.addProperty("image", strBase64); 
                        //////////////////////WebService Activity ///////////////////////

                        String METHOD_NAME = "";
                        // our webservice method name
                        String NAMESPACE = "http://test.com";
                        String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
                        // NAMESPACE + method name


                        //final String URL = "http://192.168.3.106:8080/axis2/services/speechmain?wsdl";

                        final String URL="http://192.168.3.106:8080/axis2/services/VoiceService?wsdl";

                            METHOD_NAME = "get_wav_byte";
                            try {
                                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


                            request.addProperty("wavbite", temp);

                            request.addProperty("path", "D:\\sound\\latest_recognizer.wav");
                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                            new MarshalBase64().register(envelope); // serialization

                            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
                                envelope.dotNet = true;
                                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                                Object result = envelope.getResponse();

                               // Object  result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;







                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.gettext1)).setText("NUMBER IS :->   "
                                         + result.toString());

                            } catch (Exception E) {
                                E.printStackTrace();
                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.gettext1)).setText("ERROR:"
                                        + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
                            }




                        /////////////////////////












                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }; 
}
```

What i can understand is Some How Its not Working Because I am Using External jar file in that public static String recognize_wave(String wavePath) Method.

I have Search a Lot But Still No Good Guidance Is yet Available..

Hope You can Help me..

thanks in advance ..

Comment: put jar(Library)file into libs folder into applicaton...

Comment: Thanks for response, but I have already done that part and got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your external jar file is included in your build path as well as being in your libs folder. If you don't have a libs folder you can create one in the root of your project. Then copy and paste your jar file to this location. Then right click on the jar file from within Eclipse and go to `Build Path` then click on `Add To Build Path`. If you have the jar file in your libs folder you wont get any compiler errors. But that is only for compile time. It will fail at runtime if the jar is not in the build path.